# JQuery mobile dateBox icon size

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to change the size of the button in the input box of a dateBox??

Now it looks like this:

[image]

But I would like it to be bigger because right now it turns tricky to make a clean click on it! It would also be good if instead of just the icon opening the calendar a click in any part of the input tag would open it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try look at DOM of JQuery Mobile with Firebug or google chrome and you can change icon size into class. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

The datebox stylesheet ( http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css ) references a single datebox.png sprite ( http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/image/datebox.png ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a datebox.png icon with a bigger size.

Comment: Thanks!I'll try it, but do you know where I can download the default icons of JQuery mobile???